# Find good bounds for the inverse of a function

Tags: real-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

## The general case:

Let $f : A\subset \mathbb R \to B = f(A)\subset \mathbb R$ be a $\mathcal C^\infty$-diffeormorphism.

Find good polynomial bounds for $f$ at any order (i.e. $P,Q \in \mathbb R_n[X]$ such as $\forall x \in B, P(x)\leq f(x) \leq Q(x)$ for every $n$).

What I mean by that, is, for example, we can show that if $f^{-1}=\cos$, $\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1} \frac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{(2k)!}\leq \cos(x) \leq \sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{(2k)!}$ for $x\geq 0$.

## A specific case:

Let $f : (2\alpha/\pi,+\infty) \to f((2\alpha/\pi,+\infty)), s \mapsto A(\cos(\frac{\alpha}{s}))^{-s}\sin(\frac{2\alpha}{s})+B(\cos(\frac{\alpha}{s}))^{-s}\sin(\frac{\alpha}{s})$ With $A,B,\alpha >0$ three fixed parameters.

I have to consider this function for some modelisation I'm working on. I want to find good bounds of its inverse.

---

I don't really know how to do it. I would have consider the Taylor development of the inverse $f^{-1}$ , but I don't know how to deduce bounds.

Comment: Your specific case has vertical asymptotes whenever $\cos\frac\alpha s = 0$. As such, it cannot be bounded by any polynomial, and its domain cannot be all of $\Bbb R^+$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair You are right. I just edited it and narrowed down its domain.

Comment: But not enough. You still have $|f| \to \infty$ as $s \to \frac{2\alpha}\pi +$. You have to back the domain away from the asymptote before it can be bounded by a polynomial. In general for $f$ to boundable by polynomials, it has to be bounded on any bounded set (that is a necessary condition, not sufficient).

Comment: Sorry - I just realized you are looking for bounds on the inverse of $f$, not $f$ itselt. I'm not sure yet about the behavior of the inverse. But the first step is to restrict the domain to where $f$ is $1-1$. Otherwise it won't have an inverse to bound.

Comment: @PaulSinclair what do you mean by $1-1$? I'll edit my post with a study of $f$ to find out whether this domain is small enough to have $f$ bijective.

Comment: "one-to-one". That is, injective. You already account for the codomain in the post to have it surjective, so injectivity is all that is needed to be bijective. It is obvious that your special case has the potential for injectivity problems, with the trig functions, and that was all I was referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your special case, $\lim_{s\to\infty} f(s) = 0$. Also there is a point $s_0$ with $f$ decreasing on $[s_0, +\infty)$. Exactly how low $s_0$ can be taken is difficult to determine, but because of the $\sin \frac{2\alpha}s$ factor, it is going to be somewhere around $\frac {4\alpha}\pi$, well above the asymptote caused by the cosine factor.

If we restrict $f$ to $[s_0,\infty)$, then it is injective and can be inverted. $f^{-1}$ has domain $(0,f(s_0)]$, but $\lim_{x \to 0+} f^{-1}(x) = \infty$, from which it decreases to $s_0$. Again, you have a function with a vertical asymptote. It will not be boundable by any polynomial over this entire domain.

So you cannot use polynomials to bound an inverse of $f$ whose domain extends down to $0$. Because $f$ itself is infinite at $\frac {2\alpha}\pi$ there must be at least two other domains on which $f$ is injective. These domains are bounded, so if you restrict $f$ to them, the corresponding $f^{-1}$ will have bounded codomain - i.e., you can bound it with constants.

I do not know what is appropriate for your situation.